# How to make Gcam work on POCO F1

Tags: xiaomi-pocophone-f1

I have tried many different APK's available online on my POCO F1, but none seems working fine. Can someone provide me the best GCam links for POCO F1?

Answer (score 0):

The best resource for all Gcam links for POCO F1 is available under XDA forums which are listed under [https://www.celsoazevedo.com](https://www.celsoazevedo.com/files/android/google-camera/dev-san1ty/.)

Please make sure you read and follow the instructions properly before downloading and installing it on your android device.

When you choose the APK to download, make sure your Android OS version is compatible with the APK version to be installed.